# -jQuery Form plugin- Working with multiple targets / data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working with the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form) and was not able to find a solution for the following issue in their API:

With `.ajaxForm` i want to retrieve 3 or more fields out of a database. The content of each field should be written in 3 matching elements on `index.php`. I can get and write a single field by using

```
target: '#element1'
```

in my javascript file and by using

```
echo $content ;
```

in the matching php-script.

So how can i return more data in a single script? My thought was to return an array, but i have no idea how i target the different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once more, i figured it out.

So if there anytime someone will be who is trying to:

**Fill a HTML Form with Database content without refreshing the Page**

Here is how it can be done:

You'll need the following:

1. The [html](http://pastebin.com/CyLfBJBv) with the form you want to fill
2. The [PHP](http://pastebin.com/4B0wktqk) script which gets your data from the database
3. The [jQuery](http://pastebin.com/TXqAEJdn) script which is handling both

I hope i did not miss something, got quite a headache after this. Feel free to ask.